# Store user data in Windows 8 metro app

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I am learning how to develop Windows 8 Metro style apps but i couldn't found a way to store user data in SQL Server for example.

What could i use or how to store user data.

Comment: As of now, you are expected to store data in the cloud.  This may well change at launch time, hard to predict.

Comment: which cloud should i use

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Answer (score 9):

You cannot access local "desktop services" from the Metro app. So you will not be able to communicate with a local SQL Server.
You can use online services that store your information or you can use local storage.

Take a look at:

- [How to store and retrieve local application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [ApplicationData sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2)

That question is also debated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e9cdd75d-03e4-4577-988e-4c02a52e3f50) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/52c5459d-66b9-4706-b605-9a323abefd5b)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQLite for Windows Runtime

Here is a blog post explaining how to use it:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways of storing data - Roaming Settings (if you want the same data to be available across all the win8 devices he has installed your application), Application Settings in Isolated Storage. About storing data in SQL server, as you cannot deploy sql database with Metro app, you need to have a client-server arch to host your service in front of a sql server db.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers you've already gotten, don't forget standard HTML5 localStorage, which should work across platforms and therefore help code reusability. What's not a standard is how much space you're allowed, but the de facto standard amount is about 5MB in all platforms. It might be more on Windows 8 for Metro style apps, but that's just a guess.